# Using EntityFramework in C# when using Entities for a long time

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, lifetime

I'm struggling with the following problem.

I have a database with a table *Jobs*, which contains information about Jobs to be done. I followed the Code First approach of EF 6.0 and create a POCO class called *Job*. I then query the database for the Jobs:

```
DbSet<Job> receivedJobs;
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    receivedJobs = (from j in context.Jobs
            select j);
}
```

With the received set *receivedJobs* I will then do a time consuming optimization.

As I understand it, the lifetime of the context as well as the resources the context controls ends with the closing bracket of the using statement. Also a good design should free resources to the database as soon as it is no longer required.

My question is now what should I do in my case? Just keep the database context alive until I finished my time consuming optimisation task. Or close the connection as it is not needed until the optimisation ends. But in the latter case what do I do with the disposed *Job* objects, because I will then need to access some navigation properties of them which I can't because the context was closed. (And by the way the data in the instances of the *Job* class will not be changed by the optimization. So it is not required to keep track of changes to these objects, because there will be none)

Hope someone can help me to understand what is the recommended design in this case.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always hold a context for the least amount of time necessary to do the operations. In your case, it sounds like you will need the context until the optimization is done because you are using some of its methods for navigating the result set. If that is the case, then the context should be held until you don't need it.

The bad habit to avoid is to hold onto a context when you have no immediate need for it. You will see some applications that wrongly create a context on application start and hold it for the life of the application. That is bad and a waste of resources.

In your case, put the optimization code in place, use the context until the code is completed, then release the context. Your using statement will take care of all the messy disposal stuff. Just get your code that needs the context in the {} for the using and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I forget to mention the following thing I added to my original post just after you answered my question.  

"And by the way the data in the instances of the Job class will not be changed by the optimization. So it is not required to keep track of changes to these objects, because there will be none"

Also the optimization can involve user action.

Even in this case I should keep the connection open (it could be some time)?

Answer (score 1):

Altough it will not solve all of your issues, specially the design ones,do you know the "Include" function which preloads the navigation properties of you jobs?
For example if a job points to a list of Tasks thanks to property named "Tasks":

> context.Jobs.Include("Tasks") //will preload the Tasks property of
>   your job.
>
> context.Jobs.Include("Tasks.AllowedUsers") //will preload the Tasks
>   property of your job, and the AllowedUsers list of each task.

If you want to preload several properties at same level, just use something like:

> context.Jobs.Include("Tasks").Include("OtherTasksOnJob")

Comment: I read about this function. But this requires to load more data from the database then I need at that moment. But true it solves the problem. But will I be able to use the receivedJobs set after the context was closed?

Comment: You will be able to read the receivedJobs + all included navigation properties. You'll need to reopen a connection for updates.